# Can I realize dependency injection in my RSpec tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dependency-injection, rspec

I'm refactoring my tests. I thought to myself that I should separate logic responsible for handling if proper user is logged in and logic of my successful behavior. So I started with creating a shared example with my unsuccessful contexts, but I got stuck in this moment:

```
RSpec.shared_examples "changing status" do |arguments|
  /* ... */

  it_behaves_like "action requiring proper user logged in to be successful", action

  context "- when the required logged user is logged in" do
    before(:each) do
      /* ... */
    end
    context "and when the reservation has an allowed status" do
      /* ... */
    end
    context "and when the reservation has a not allowed status" do
      /* ... */
    end
  end
end
RSpec.shared_examples "action requiring proper user logged in to be successful" do |action|
  context "- when the logged in user is not the required logged user" do
    before(:each) do
      login(incidental_user)
    end
    it_behaves_like "unsuccessful attempt to change the reservation", action
  end
  context "- when there's no user logged in" do
    it_behaves_like "unsuccessful attempt to change the reservation", action
  end
end
```

So, I'd like to inject the code from my context `"when the required logged user is logged in"` to my shared example to make it clean. I tried to do it with anonymous code blocks and `yield` keyword:

```
RSpec.shared_examples "changing status" do |arguments|
  /* ... */

  it_behaves_like "action requiring proper user logged in to be successful", action do
    before(:each) do
      /* ... */
    end
    context "and when the reservation has an allowed status" do
      /* ... */
    end
    context "and when the reservation has a not allowed status" do
      /* ... */
    end
  end

end
RSpec.shared_examples "action requiring proper user logged in to be successful" do |action|
  context "- when the required logged user is logged in" do
    yield
  end
  context "- when the logged in user is not the required logged user" do
    before(:each) do
      login(incidental_user)
    end
    it_behaves_like "unsuccessful attempt to change the reservation", action
  end
  context "- when there's no user logged in" do
    it_behaves_like "unsuccessful attempt to change the reservation", action
  end
end
```

But unfortunately it get this error:

> LocalJumpError: no block given (yield)

So, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved my problem using lambda:

```
RSpec.shared_examples "changing status" do |arguments|
  /* ... */

  it_behaves_like "action requiring proper user logged in to be successful", action, -> {
    before(:each) do
      /* ... */
    end
    context "and when the reservation has an allowed status" do
      /* ... */
    end
    context "and when the reservation has a not allowed status" do
      /* ... */
    end
  }
end
RSpec.shared_examples "action requiring proper user logged in to be successful" do |action, successful_behavior|
  context "- when the required logged user is logged in" do
    successful_behavior.()
  end
  context "- when the logged in user is not the required logged user" do
    before(:each) do
      login(incidental_user)
    end
    it_behaves_like "unsuccessful attempt to change the reservation", action
  end
  context "- when there's no user logged in" do
    it_behaves_like "unsuccessful attempt to change the reservation", action
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question.

You could do it in a one, encapsulated example, but there is another, IMO clearer way:

Make a separate `shared_example`s for positive and negative tests. The negative one you have worked out, so you're good (just change the name, to make it clear it's a negative set of tests).

And the positive one can look like this:

```
RSpec.shared_examples 'restricted action with logged in user' do
  before { login(authorized_user) }

  specify do
    expect_stuff_typical_for_logged_in_user
    # e.g. expect(response).to be_success
  end
end
```

And then in your specs include it with [`include_examples`](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples), like this

```
context do 
  include_examples 'restricted action with logged in user'
  # you're "inside" the context of included examples so you can 
  # write down extra expectations specific for each action
end
```

There could be a case that your positive part does not have common expectations, just sets up context - you may consider using [shared_context](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-7/docs/example-groups/shared-context) to communicate your intentions clearly.

You could cramp it all up in one shared example like this:

```
RSpec.shared_examples "action requiring proper user logged in to be successful" do
  # set up the context for positive scenarios, so you can include it with 
  # `include_examples` and be "inside" this context
  before { login(authorized_user) }

  context "- when the logged in user is not the required logged user" do
    before(:each) do
      login(incidental_user)
    end
    it_behaves_like "unsuccessful attempt to change the reservation"
  end
  context "- when there's no user logged in" do
    before { log_out_people }
    it_behaves_like "unsuccessful attempt to change the reservation"
  end
end
```

There are two problems with that. First, you set up a positive context and then you have to undo it in negative examples (It feels [smelly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)).
Secondly, it's may not be obvious what is going on in the specs.
They will look like this:

```
context do
  include_examples 'action requiring proper user logged in to be successful'

  specify do
    expect(response).not_to be_redirect
  end

  context 'when user have not seen changes TOS' do
    before { }
    specify do
      expect(session[:notice]).to eq 'Please read new TOS'
    end
end
```

And it's not clear at all, that the negative examples are covered.

And then, if in any place you need custom expectations for the **negative** case - you'll need to split those anyway.

You can decide to go either way be aware of the trade-offs.

Comment: I think I understand, although you could edit your examples to make it more readable. I guess you mean that your context from the second codeblock you want to put instead of your comments in your third codeblock? I think one block with full solution would be more clear. And one more small problem: I cannot see any dependency injection here. I cannot feel free to inject anything to my shared example.

Comment: `include_examples` and `it_behaves_like` behave differently. It's explained in the docs I've linked.